# command-line z-base-32 encode/decode

Tags: command-line

Is there any command-line utility that can encode content using z-base-32? (described in [RFC6189 point 5.1.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6189#section-5.1.6), see also [wikipedia info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#z-base-32))
it seems `base32` cannot do it and googling has not helped either.

currently I'm doing

```
base32 |sed -e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567/ybndrfg8ejkmcpqxot1uwisza345h769/'
```

but this seems lame and is probably ineffective for big input...